# Lambda/Closure size causing timeout at compilation

Tags: swift, lambda, compilation, closures

I'm writing a function that calculates the moves of a knight in the game of chess. This function will take knight pieces of type `UInt64` and map them with my lambda function, `knightMovementLambda`, and return the list of new `UInt64`.

I'm confused as to why my lambda function takes so much time to compile to the point Xcode throws a timeout error. As far as I understand, below is a valid lambda in Swift. My questions is, does Swift impose a size restriction on the expression in the lambda at compilation time?

```
let FILE_A:UInt64 = 0x0101010101010101
let FILE_B:UInt64 = 0x0202020202020202
let FILE_G:UInt64 = 0x4040404040404040
let FILE_H:UInt64 = 0x8080808080808080

func getKnightMoves() -> [UInt64] {

    /* Unrelated setup/variables */

    let knightMovementLambda:(UInt64) -> UInt64 = {(x:UInt64) -> UInt64 in
            (~FILE_A & x) << 17 |
            (~(FILE_A | FILE_B) & x) << 10 |
            (~(FILE_A | FILE_B) & x) >> 6 |
            (~FILE_A & x) >> 15 |
            (~FILE_H & x) << 15 |
            (~(FILE_G|FILE_H) & x) << 6 |
            (~(FILE_G|FILE_H) & x) >> 10 |
            (~FILE_H & x) >> 17
    }

    /* Return valid moves list after mapping */

    return []

}
```

Comment: I assume you’re getting the standard “The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time; try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions” (or something like that) error. If so, it’s not a question of the size of the closure, but rather the complexity of a single expression. Break it up into separate statements within the closure and the warning should go away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swift has difficulty type checking large expressions.  Break your statement into sub-expressions like this for example:

```
let knightMovementLambda: (UInt64) -> UInt64 = { (x: UInt64) -> UInt64 in
    var result = (~FILE_A & x) << 17
    result |= (~(FILE_A | FILE_B) & x) << 10
    result |= (~(FILE_A | FILE_B) & x) >> 6
    result |= (~FILE_A & x) >> 15
    result |= (~FILE_H & x) << 15
    result |= (~(FILE_G|FILE_H) & x) << 6
    result |= (~(FILE_G|FILE_H) & x) >> 10
    result |= (~FILE_H & x) >> 17

    return result
}
```